# Load HTML5 Video only when it is shown

Tags: jquery, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a bunch of different boxes of content. Each box contains a video.

Only one box is displayed at a time. Since there are 12 or so videos being loaded on page load, the page loads quite slowly.

Is there a way to only load a video when it is shown (ie. display:block as opposed to display:none)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh924823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There is some useful information there. I would imagine you would just use jquery and check if the div is displayed block. If it is then run some function that gets the video. I don't see you getting around using anything besides javascript.